# DataGridRow.IsEditing never returns true

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Suppose I have 5 columns and 5 rows in my DataGrid. Now I want to get all the cells of currentRow in edit mode. I successfully done that. Now I want to disable all the rows except the Row in which cells are editing. But in below code `r.IsEditing` never return true. Can somebody explain me why????

```
for (int column = 0; column <= dg.Columns.Count - 1; column++)
{
    if (!(GetDataGridCell(new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[column])).IsReadOnly))
    {
        GetDataGridCell(new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[column])).IsEditing = true;
    }
}

foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
{
    if (!(r.IsEditing))
    {
        r.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was little tricky. I needed to add the below lines to my code to make it work:

```
dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[0]);
dg.BeginEdit();
```

So, now my complete code looks like:

```
dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[0]);
dg.BeginEdit();

for (int column = 0; column <= dg.Columns.Count - 1; column++)
{
    if (!(GetDataGridCell(new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[column])).IsReadOnly))
    {
        GetDataGridCell(new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[column])).IsEditing = true;
    }
}

foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
{
    if (!(r.IsEditing))
    {
        r.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```